# Ensure your program starts in Windows Safe Mode

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

Is there a way I can ensure that my program starts even in the "Windows Safe Mode" ?

Comment: That kind of defeats the object of safe mode, but you could try deploying it as a windows service

Comment: Why wouldn't your program start? Does it depend on a service that isn't available in safe mode?

Comment: It is deployed as a Windows Service, but in safe mode the service does not start. How does Windows know which services to start in Safe mode ?

Comment: Do you mean starts as in "it can execute and run in safe mode" or starts as in "automatically starts running at startup/login"?

Comment: It does not execute and run in Safe mode but starts automatically and runs perfectly well in normal startup/login. I want it to start/execute in windows safe mode

Comment: @ Gabe: The service is independent and does not depend on any other Windows Service. But, I want to ensure it starts even in a safe mode. Where is the list of services windows decides to start even in "safe-mode". If I put my service in that list, I guess, I am done !

Comment: Why is your service so important that it needs to run in Safe Mode? What if the user can't boot because your service is causing problems?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do so. One of the easiest way to do this is adding your app in Windows registry.

> Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

Here you will find a String value with default value data

> Shell = explorer.exe

Now you can add your app here by editing its value data, so that after edit it will look like

> Shell = explorer.exe,app1,app2

This will make these apps to run in safe mode.

Warning: Do not remove explorer.exe . Doing this will prevent auto start of Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Safe mode is a mode of windows in which only the very bare minimum core windows features are started.

By design it does not load or automatically start up any 3rd party applications, services or drivers.

The purpose is to have a minimal running version of windows incase one of those 3rd party apps, services or drivers are malfunctioning and preventing windows from working correctly.

Comment: Do you know HKLM\SYstem\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot registry key ? It is safeboot configuration. My drivers are added too. Your last statement is wrong.